# Automatically merging two codebases using Jenkins pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to make a Jenkins pipeline which merges the develop branch in the master branch. The develop branch has some basic steps like npm install etc. The master branch handles the release etc.

I have two different Jenkinsfile, one in the develop branch and one in the master branch. When the merging happens, it will also try to merge the Jenkinsfile of develop with master.

How do I avoid this?
Do I remove the Jenkinsfile from develop and use when{}-conditions in the pipeline or is there another (better) solution?

Thanks in advance!
Regards